# Right way to call headers in c

Tags: c, header, modular

I'm new in c programming.

I'm playing with an exercise where I created a main program called main.c that includes two other modules: modulo1 and modulo2 with rispettives headers.

Modulo1 contains some data and functions while modulo2 calls data and functions defined modulo1.

I put the lists:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "modulo1.h"
#include "modulo2.h"

vector v1;
vector v2;
vector sm;

int
main (int argc,
      char *argv[])
{
  create(& v1 ,1 ,2 );
  create(& v2 ,3 ,2 );
  sum(& sm, & v1, & v2);

  report (& v1);
  report (& v2);
  report (& sm);

  printf("\n-----------------\nDone !\n-----------------\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where
modulo1.h

```
struct vector
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

typedef struct vector vector;

void create(vector *v, int x, int y);
void sum(vector *sum, vector *v1, vector *v2);
```

modulo1.c

```
#include "modulo1.h"

void create(vector *v, int x, int y)
{
  v->x = x;
  v->y = y;
}

void sum(vector *sum, vector *v1, vector *v2)
{
  sum->x = v1->x + v2->x;
  sum->y = v1->y + v2->y;
}
```

and then the second modulo2.h

```
//#include "modulo2.h"
void report(vector *v);
```

and the modulo2.c is

```
#include "modulo2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void report(vector *v)
{
  printf("\n------------------\n The vector is:\n x:=%d\n y:=%d\n------------------\n", v->x, v->y);
}
```

When I build all like this I get some errors similar to this:

```
....modulo2.h:2:13: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
```

while when I include in modula2.h the #include "modulo1.h" I get another groups of errors like this following:

```
.....modulo1.h:1:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct vector’
```

The makefile is very easy:

```
modula1_SOURCES = \
main.c \
modulo1.c \
modulo1.h \
modulo2.c \
modulo2.h
```

I cannot understand where is the error and where I'm wrong.
Someone can help me ?
I think there is something wrong at header / include files ?

Thank you

Marco

Answer (score 4):

> When I build all like this I get some errors similar to this:
>
> ```
> ....modulo2.h:2:13: error: unknown type name ‘vector’
> ```

Because `modulo2.h` uses identifiers declared in `modulo1.h`, it needs to include `modulo1.h`.

> … when I include in modula2.h the #include "modulo1.h" I get another groups of errors like this following:
>
> ```
> .....modulo1.h:1:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct vector’
> ```

Because `main.c` includes `modulo1.h` and includes `modulo2.h` and the latter also includes `modulo1.h`, we have `modulo1.h` included twice, and so there are multiple definitions.

A way to resolve this is to use what are called header guards. In `modulo1.h`, we can put these lines at the beginning and the end:

```
#if !defined modulo1_h
#define modulo1_h
…
#endif // #if !defined modulo1_h
```

This will cause the contents of `modulo1.h` between those lines to be compiled only once:

- The first time `modulo1.h` is included, `modulo1_h` is not defined, so `!defined modulo1_h` is true, and everything in the file is compiled.
- That includes defining `modulo1_h` (with an empty replacement list).
- The second time `modulo1.h` is included, `modulo1_h` is already defined, so `!defined modulo1_h` is false, and the rest of the file is not compiled.

This way, each file, whether it is `main.c`, `modulo2.h`, or another file can include `modulo1.h` if it needs any identifiers from that header, and it does not have to be concerned with whether anything has included it previously. If it has been included previously, there will be no multiple definitions. If it has not been included previously, its definitions (and declarations) will be applied.

Comment: I applied this method and it works. thank you